# old android sdk for download

Tags: eclipse-plugin, adt, android-2.2-froyo

Does anybody know of a ftp server / mirror where I could get some older Android SDK ? Older than http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html at least, has to work with ADT r16.0.1

Comment: *"I am in trouble and blah blah and whatnot yadday yadda. I am in trouble and blah blah and whatnot yadday yadda I am in trouble and blah blah and whatnot yadday yadda I am in trouble and blah blah and whatnot yadday yadda"* - what?

Comment: sorry, i have meant to put each on separate lines but the formatting of SO wrapped them all on a few lines.

Comment: oh, I just bumped into http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r16-macosx.zip

Found according to http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Android_SDK#Old_versions

Answer (score 0):

You could find the appropriate tag and check it out of source control

https://github.com/android

and use whatever version you want.

Comment: seemed ike a good lead at first but on second thought i think it involves a lot of work to assemble what comes as android-sdk on the dl page mentioned. Thanks anyway